# Swift Storing information in a constant and keeping it there

Tags: swift

Hello I am currently doing a project where the user types something in a textfield, and presses a button, where whatever the user types in the textfield appears as part of the alertbody of a notification. 
To do this I save the textfield.text as a variable and then use string interpolation to include it into the alertbody.
The problem is that the time in which I fire the notifications change every week, so I have to make new notifications. And I still want to use whatever the user typed into the textfield. But since the textfield.text was saved inside a function, I do not think that it will be stored outside the function.
This is what my code looks like so far

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(604800, target: self,selector:Selector("repeater"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

savedtext:String!    

@IBAction func setNotification{
textfield.text = savedtext
 //set notifications and other stuff here
}
//outside the function savedtext should not have the textfield's info
func repeater{
//setting notification
}
```

Sorry if my question is a bit difficult to understand
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `NSUserDefaults` here, it will persist your data in a key-value map, even after the user or system kills the app. The code would look like this

```
let ALERT_MESSAGE_KEY : String = "myAlertMsgKey"

@IBAction func setNotification{
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   defaults.setValue(textfield.text , forKey: ALERT_MESSAGE_KEY) 
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
  //set notifications and other stuff here
}
```

and in repeater function:

```
func repeater {
   let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
   let alertMessage = defaults.valueForKey(ALERT_MESSAGE_KEY) as? String ?? "No message saved"
}
```

You could also use Core Data for this, but it would be an overkill for something so simple

Comment: Thanks alot, your answer helped alot

Comment: Is there any way to set a default value for something stored in `NSUserDefaults`, which the user can change, after which it won't revert back to the default? Or should I use a plist for that?